# Mail Notification sound won't disable

Tags: mail.app, notifications

I have disabled mail notification sounds in Mojave 10.14.6:

[image]

However, the Notification sound still plays for new mail. Even setting notifications to None does not help. The alert is gone, but the sound is still there. 
Is there anything else that can be tried?

Comment: This potentially has other points of 'switching' Check mail Prefs > General that the new messages sound is on [& others beneath that]. There's also the potential that you have Rules set up that will suppress the new mail sound.

Comment: Ha, indeed there is a separate in-app setting. Very confusing.

Comment: I've never quite figured out the interplay between all those potential 'switches'. I have the opposite where some of my rule-filtered mails which *should* make the sound… don't :\